# Not allowing connection to email servers

Tags: windows-7, windows, email, smtp, email-client

I have no idea why its doing this or what's wrong.

Suddenly our company Windows 7 laptop stopped sending and receiving emails. The problem it gives in outlook is that a connection cannot be made to the servers.

This error is replicated in Thunderbird and other email clients. Even pinging/telneting on the ports 25, 110 etc don't seem to work.

We have genuine windows 7 but unfortunately the laptop didn't come with an installation dvd so we cannot reinstall windows unless we order a dvd. I'm sure this is an issue with something other than the windows system though.

Laptop: HP ProBook 4320s (no recovery partition afaik - there's a HP Tools partition)
Error: "Could not connect to pop.domain.com. The connection was refused."

We have many computers (windows and mac) connecting to the mail servers on a daily basis, so there's nothing wrong with the server.

If you need any more information then please let me know.

Comment: Just wondering, does this also happen when booted from a Linux CD? Does the mail server name resolve to the correct IP addresses? Also, could it be that the server's firewall is blocking the laptop specifically?

Comment: Make sure that the laptop can get to out the mail server.  Is it having any other network connectivity issues?  Have any of the network settings recently changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you checked  client's firefall rules (if other can connect and this can't, reasons can be local)?
2. Did you tried change IP of client and test connectivity (if this host can't connect, it can be filtered by server's rules, IP-based)?
3. Did you tried connect to other services on another hosts in your net (you can just haven't connectivity at all at physical level)?
4. Did your company hired real, qualified admin?